# 1 Consumer which takes from differents queues RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have 3 queues with different priority. I need that the consumer read from these queues. I declared and configured the priority of the queues on RabbitMQ web interface. I used `x-maximum-priority` parameter to set differents values (https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html).

This is the code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, TimeoutException, InterruptedException
{
        .... 
        //Conection details



        System.out.println(" [x] Waiting ");


        Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
                AMQP.BasicProperties replyProps = new AMQP.BasicProperties
                      .Builder()
                      .correlationId(properties.getCorrelationId())
                      .build();



                String message = new String(body,"UTF-8");

                System.out.println(message);
                Thread.sleep(2000);//To simulate a big operation




                channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);

      };


      channel.basicConsume("high_priority", false, consumer);
      channel.basicConsume("medium_priority", false, consumer);             
      channel.basicConsume("low_priority", false ,consumer);                    



}
```

but the consumer takes from the first queue and when is empty it takes from the second and when is empty it takes from the third.

Is it a bad approach? Is it better use 3 consumers? Could works with consumer priorities? (https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html)

**UPDATE:**

I expect that the consumer takes the messages in differents order. I want that the consumer takes from high-priority-queue and occasionally takes from the others queues depending on the priority. I need to consume all messages in an intertwined way. I don't want that the low priority messages never be consume because high priority message overtakes always.

**EXAMPLE:**

I have 3 queues: high-priority, medium-priority, low-priority and for example i want that the consumer takes 10 messages from high-priority queue, 4 messages from medium-priority queue and 1 message from low-priority queue.

Comment: What is your use case exactly? Your current workaround sounds some tricky, may be there could be a better way to handle it.

Comment: You have to make one extra queue in RabbitMQ and redirect your queue to it.

Comment: you described what you did and what it does, but you forgot to explain the most important thing, **what you want resp. expect**

Comment: @EmreSavcı I need to read from the differents queues with differents priorities without queues filling up. Over the queues are traveling tasks requests with differents priorities.

Comment: @talex what do you mean? Redirect from 3 queues to 1 queue?

Comment: What is the need for 3 different queues? Are there represents different events or commands or purposes?

Comment: I want precise enough. You have to bind your 3 *exchange* to single queue and manage all the priorities in RabbitMQ. When message hit consumer it is to late to prioritize.

Comment: You don't need to break into 3 priority queues. Only 1 queue with messages of different priorities. Your consumer will get first those with higher priority an so on. Just make sure that your producer delivers messages with the proper priority to RMQ.

Comment: The queues represents 3 SLAs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) which i have to ensure without block each other.

Comment: @talex  But i think that the message with low priority never be cosumed by the consumer because when a high priority message arrives, it's going to overtake it . I need all messages be consumed

Comment: I don't know how exactly priorities work. In your scenario if consumer do not have enough capacity to consume all the messages some of them will not be processed. Do you want it to be high or low priority messages?

Comment: @Maverick94 Sorry English is not my first language. I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: @talex maybe with an example is clearer. 

I have 3 queues: high-priority, medium-priority, low-priority and for example i want that the consumer takes 10 messages from high-priority queue, 4 messages from medium-priority queue and 1 message from low-priority queue

Comment: @AKSW I updated the post.

Comment: I doubt that RabbitMQ is capable of such complex behavior. Only way I see how to do that is create 3 separate consumer and  manually implement priorities.

Comment: @talex 3 consumers with differents priorities?

Comment: @Maverick94 from RabbitMQ point of view no. I doubt it capable to set priorities this way.